# Connect two machines using jgroups

Tags: jgroups

I'm trying to run the Draw example and communicate between two different machines. It works fine on same machine using this command:

```
java -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw
```

Now I tried giving the IPv4Address of the other machine in bind_addr and it gave me an error saying

```
/'other.machine.ip' is not a valid address on any local network interface
```

Please tell me the command or what `bind_addr` should I give for the both machines to connect.
Sorry I just started on this, so please tell me in simple works and exact details.

**EDIT:**

Ok. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded jgroups.jar
2. Gave the CLASSPATH like this: "C:\jgroups\jgroups-3.6.1.Final.jar"
3. Extracted the jar file.
4. Ran this command on machine A: `java -Djgroups.bind_addr="Gave local IPv4 Address" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw`
5. Ran this command on machine B: `java -Djgroups.bind_addr="Gave local IPv4 Address" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw`
6. But I was unable to communicate (Drew something on machine A and it was not updated on machine B)

**Note:** By the way, I was able to ping both machines. And I also disabled the firewall just in case.

Am I doing something wrong or is missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**

**SOLVED!**

As it turned out, I was doing everything right. What I did was just downloaded the previous version of jgroups (in my case, `3.4.7`). And everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

bind_addr needs to be the IP address of the *local* machine. It cannot be 127.0.0.1 because that won't get routed to other boxes, so use a link local address, e.g. 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x.
Assuming you use udp.xml with UDP:PING, that's all you need to do. If you use TCP, you'll need to set a bind_port in TCP and list all of your instances in TCPPING.initial_hosts, e.g. initial_hosts="192.168.1.1[7800],192.168.1.5[7800],..."

Comment: Please see my latest edit and see if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ping other.machine.ip ?

For my setup I use the following system properties -

-Djgroups.bind_port=7802 -Djgroups.bind_addr=HOST3 -Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts=HOST1[7800],HOST2[7801],HOST3[7802]

Could be worth trying those on each process

Comment: Yes, I'm able to ping but when I try to give the ip of one machine in the bind_addr it give that BindException.

Comment: Should I use my machine's port and ip in bind_port and bind_addr or what ?